# axistools:wsdl2java plugin: Can we rename downloaded wsdl

Tags: maven, axis

We are using `axistools:wsdl2java` plugin for generating java stubs corresponding to wsdl.

We are using following option for this:

```
<configuration>
<urls>
  <url>${URL}</url>
</urls>                                                     
<packageSpace>x.y.z</packageSpace>                          
</configuration>
```

But the problem that the name of the wsdl file downloaded contains complete url. I want to rename downloaded wsdls, is there any option to do that by Maven itself?